# Using public facing forms in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: forms, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I need to provide a public facing form (e.g a contact us form), where the details will end up in CRM. What's the easiest / recommended way to accomplish this?

1. Write the form myself, and make a service call to CRM on submit
2. Write the form myself, send an email to CRM on submit
3. Use something already built into CRM to generate the form?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a thesis on this question however i'll try to reply simply! :-)

If you are working in a Microsoft .Net environment then writing a form and making a service call on submit is quite straight forward and I would recommend this approach. There is lots of good samples out there usually written in C#.

If you are NOT in a Microsoft space (Think Wordpress, Joomla etc) then service calls become a pain and the email is probably way to go (although truth be told I haven't done this!).

There is nothing built in to Dynamics CRM to generate the form as far as i'm aware.  They have tried it in the past however it was limited to North America only and over time it has been removed from the solution.

Comment: The fact that this doesn't exist is so mind boggling as to the point it hurts. How the hell can a company like Microsoft create a product that is supposed to help ROI and convert leads to sales not have a tool to create a webform in order to capture a lead where someone just wants to say, hey give me info on your widget. It literally hurts my head so bad I can't speak.